# How to shift element from one array position to another in MongoDB with mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have got an array of objects in MongoDB and I was moving a particular element id (i.e 1) from its position to below element having id (i.e 2). So that we can get element with id as 2 -> 1 -> 3.

```
const arr = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'foo'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'bar'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'zoo'
  }
]
```

What I've done is used $pull and $push but it gives **ConflictingUpdateOperators** and I don't know how to deal with it.

```
updatedPlan = await Plan.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: req.params.id },
        {
          $pull: {
                    "arr": {
                        id: 1
                    }
          },
          $push: {
                  "arr" : {
                    $each: [{ id: 1, name: 'foo'}],
                    $position: 1
                  }
          },
      );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MongoDB 4.2 or newer you can update a document with Aggregation Pipeline. Using simple [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) on a [$range](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/range/index.html) of array indexes you can shuffle these indexes and use [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/index.html) in order to build a new array:

```
db.col.update({ _id: req.params.id }, [
    {
        $set: {
            arr: {
                $map: {
                    input: { $range: [ 0, { $size: "$arr" } ] },
                    in: {
                        $let: {
                            vars: {
                                newIndex: {
                                    $switch: {
                                        branches: [
                                            { case: { "$eq": [ "$$this", 0 ] }, then: 1 },
                                            { case: { "$lte": [ "$$this", 1 ] }, then: { $subtract: [ "$$this", 1 ] } },
                                        ],
                                        default: "$$this"
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            in: {
                                $arrayElemAt: [ "$arr", "$$newIndex" ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me. I understand almost everything except the $switch part, could you please help me to understand $switch.

Comment: @DeC sure, the role of swtich is to swap the indexes -> the $range operator will return `[0,1,2]` and you want it to be `[1,0,2]` since this is the final order you want to get.

Comment: So it could be simplified and look like this `$map: { input: [1,0,2], in: { $arrayElemAt: [ "$arr", "$$this" ]} }` if you knew from your client code that it's always 3-elements set. I assumed it can vary so $range and $switch to provide more generic pattern

Comment: what if we don't have length. I mean I just wrote a generic easy to understand code.

Comment: If you don't know length then you need to rely on `$range` and substitute indexes using $cond  / $switch

Comment: I got your point but what if there is 100 element in an array and if I want to swap first element with index 0 to last element with index 999. Do I have to write 1000 switch cases?

Comment: @DeC no, that's why I used switch for swapping. In your case it will be: `{ case: { "$eq": [ "$$this", 0 ] }, then: 999 }, { case: { "$eq": [ "$$this", 999 ] }, then: 0 }` and of course `default` rewrites other indexes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221075/discussion-between-de-c-and-mickl).